# How to i make a gitignore file, nitrous.io

Tags: git, ide, nitrousio

I am using nitrous.io and i would like to push my work to git without some images. but there is no git ignore file. how can i add it?

specifically i want to push without:
public/system/courses/images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create, then add and commit a file `.gitignore` in the courses folder, with the content:

```
images/
```

(note the trailing '`/`')

If `images/` folder was already added/committed, delete it (from the git repo, not the disk)

```
git rm -r --cached images/
git add -A .
git commit -m "Record deletion of images folder"
```